# Have infants ever been instructed to bless on mothers milk?

Tags: blessing, dairy, baby-infant

[This biography](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24357&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=) of [Rabbi Zalman Volozhin](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%96%27%D7%99%D7%9F#), brother of famed [Rabbi Chaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_of_Volozhin), reports that at the age of one year old he was trained by his mother to recite a blessing before suckling her milk.

Is such an idea represented elsewhere in Jewish history?

Comment: I can't imagine this ever happening (I guess, except, in that biography you quoted?). From a practical perspective, I don't think there would ever be a 'Chiyuv' to say a Bracha, as the uper age limit for nursing is 5 years old (see [Chayei Adam 66:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam.66.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) (with most probably stopping to nurse long before then), and the main Chiyuv of Chinuch only just about starts then. And that's besides the fact that, based on a handful of random parenting sites I just perused, kids are only just starting to talk in the 1-2 yr old range.

Comment: I heard a similar report about a chasidiseh Rebbe, though I don't remember who. To judge the story tellers favorably, I would guess that these things did happen, just not at age one; maybe if they were still nursing at age four or five (see ketubos 60a).

Comment: Sure, my two-year-old niece can make a couple of Berachos, but she has no idea what she’s saying. I find it hard to believe that this is actually a psak Halacha, to lechatchilah instruct kids to make Berachos without understanding what they’re saying on any level.

Comment: This all depends upon the child. The obligation to teach a child Torah (which includes making blessings) begins as soon as the child begins speaking. The obligation is upon the father. See the following from Hilchot Talmud Torah, chapter 1, seif 1: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16009&st=&pgnum=67

Comment: @Don THIS is definitely not a psak Halacha

Comment: Did you mean "Jewish history" or "Jewish Halacha"?

Comment: It might not be halacha, but it sure is adorable.